# Do I need two lookup components used on one page to create different events?

Tags: lightning, lookup, event, component

I need two similar lookup components on one page of an App. So far, I have used the code in [Create Re-Usable Custom Lookup Component](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/)
However, these two components must listen to different events, because I want to display Account 1 and its orders and also Account 2 with its orders. So far only one event with the Account info is fired. Do I have to duplicate these two components, or how can I rewrite the lookup component or my code in order to be able to listen to two different events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could distinguish the lookup components by inserting an attribute for Lookup1 and Lookup2 that would be implemented in the parent with the attribute defined and then passed down to the child component the event gets fired. I included this attribute in the event and then could evaluate which component did fire the event.